# GFCI blown after flickering electricity due to external issue

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci, replacement

There was a fire a block from my apartment,lights in the building were flicking and a couple of breakers "jumped" and we loss power while the utility company made repairs. When I restarted the breakers, a GFCI in the kitchen started buzzing. I turned breaker off and reset 4 GFCIs in the kitchen. I turned breaker back on. Buzzing continued and this and another GFCI blown. I switched off the breaker, remove plate and inspected the outlets. No obvious melting or charred wires.

Question: Could this be faulty GFCIs and replacing them will resolve the problem, or is it a major problem with the circuit breaker?  I'm keeping breaker off and all 4 GFCIs are off for now

Thank you!

Comment: Can you use a multimeter to get voltage readings around the apartment?

Comment: Any noise coming from a GFCI device is bad if the connections are secure you probably need to replace,  one of the joys of electronics and power surges.

Comment: What does `a couple of breakers "jumped"` mean? Do you mean that the breakers "tripped" (i.e. the handle moved to the center position and power quit flowing through the circuit)? Also `Buzzing continued and this and another GFCI blown` does "blown" mean that the CFCI tripped, cutting power? Sorry, I'm sure the translation from BreathMintish to English isn't 100% :)

Comment: Thank you "Moving 2 Codidact" for your comment. I can use a multimeter to get readings from outlets around the apartment.

May I ask what the normal reading(s) should be? and the purpose of doing this? I'm not questioning your comments, I'm trying to learn! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Ed Beal for your comment. I'll replace them and see how it goes. From what I read online, GFCIs should last 10-15 years, and I believe these are hitting 20 years. 

I bought the replacements. I was going to buy 20amp GFCIs (the current ones are 20amp), but I saw an electrician and he offered advice. He told me to get 15amp ones... I wasn't sure about that, but he's supposed to know, right? Once at home I Google it, since I've read that kitchen appliances use a bit of amps, and there it was, there could be some 15amp GFCIs in the kitchen, but there must be two 20amp GGCIs too.

Comment: Hi FreeMan, Thanks for the comment. By  "blown", I mean "exploded". There were no burning marks or anything in the receptacle, the wires are ok. No obvious burning, not even on the GFCI, but there was a bit of smoke and burning smell.

Thanks for making the effort to translate from "MintyBreath" ;) to English.

Answer (score 1):

You can't assume that the GFCIs are damaged without knowing what is connected to them.  They might be interrupting part of the circuit as a life-saving function.  In other words, the fire or power anomalies could have damaged something else in the circuit that is causing a load fault detectable at those outlets.

Comment: By "jumped" I meant "tripped". I think "tripped is the correct term?